# Is it normal to use an object as its own key in a dictionary/hashmap (in python)?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

Say I have a stream of incoming items which I am processing.  For each item I extract some data and store it.  But lots of the items are the same.  I want to keep track of receiving them, but not store the same data more than once.  I can implement it like this, but it seems clunky:

```
item_cache = {}
item_record = []

def process(input_item):
    item = Item(input_item)  # implements __hash__
    try:
        item_record.append(item_cache[item])
    except KeyError:
        item_cache[item] = item  # this is the part that seems weird
        item_record.append(item)
```

I am just overthinking this?  Is doing `d[thing] = thing` a fairly normal construct in python?

***EDIT***

In response to comment below.  Here is more complete example showing how this code avoids storing duplicate copies of input data.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and self.c == other.c

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '(%s, %s, %s)' % (self.a, self.b, self.c)


item_cache = {}
item_record = []


def process_item(new_item):
    item = Item(*new_item)
    try:
        item_record.append(item_cache[item])
    except KeyError:
        item_cache[item] = item
        item_record.append(item)

    del item  # this happens anyway, just adding for clarity.

for item in ((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)):
    process_item(item)

print([id(item) for item in item_record])
print(item_record)
```

Comment: If `thing` is immutable (and it has to be, or else you cannot use it as a key), perhaps a `set()` is a better container for the cache?

Comment: Out of context,  Will it be better to use some property of Object as key `item.some_unique_id` (may be tuple/composite of other properties)
which is already hashable and hopefully immutable?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately yes. Quite a bit of over thinking in fact. All you need to do is to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference.

Your code can be replaced with

```
item_record = set()
for .... :
   item_record.add(input_item)
```

**update**
though you say ", but not store the same data more than once" your code actually does store the item more than one. In your original code, the item_record.append() call will be executed regardless of whether or not an item exists in item cache

```
try:
    item_record.append(item_cache[item])
except KeyError:
    item_cache[item] = item  # this is the part that seems weird
    item_record.append(item)
```

So the list will have duplicates. However I am not quite sure if you are appending the right objects because you haven't shared the code for your Item class. I believe that what we really have is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not post a new question and explain what you are trying to solve.

Comment: what about if I have multiple item_records?  day a new one each time i receive a new big chunk of input data.  i still want a single cache, but i can't use the same structure for the record.

Comment: i don't understand your comment

Comment: um, ok but I think it's better to clarify the comment here.

Comment: Apologies.  Let me clarify. The issue with just using a set is that I lose any idea of the order or number of the incoming items.  Say I received an item twice in succession... I want that to be reflected in the record.

Comment: @Ferguzz You only need order and number in `item_record`, right? Not in `item_cache`? So use a set for `item_cache` and keep using a list for `item_record`.

Comment: If you are trying to count objects recieved including duplicates, your code doesn't do that efficiently either. you say "but not store the same data more than once" but you are actually doing that by storing all items in a list

Comment: and in response to your edit directly.  the list has duplicate *references* to objects containing data.  but it only stores data for each unique input once.